# Join two ordered collections with LINQ

Tags: linq, join, c#-4.0, collections

I've got two data types, `Foo` and `Bar`, that have a property to determine order:

```
class Foo
{
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public string FooValue { get; set; }
}

class Bar
{
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public string BarValue { get; set; }
}
```

Then I've got two collections of these types. I'd like to join the collections, so that the result will be contain pairs of `Foo` and `Bar`. The number of pairs should be the number of `Bar` elements.

Each pair should consist of a `Bar` element and the most "recent" `Foo` element (with largest Foo `Order` value, bounded by the current Bar `Order` value).

For example, for the following collections (some statements omitted):

```
var foos = new [] { (1, "Foo1"), (2, "Foo2"), (5, "Foo5"), (7, "Foo7") };
var bars = new [] { (1, "Bar1"), (6, "Bar6") };
```

The result would be:

```
result = { 
    ((1, "Bar1"), (1, "Foo1")),
    ((6, "Bar6"), (5, "Foo5"))
};
```

How can I achieve this with LINQ and C# 4.0?

Comment: Are the `foos` sorted by `Order`?

Comment: Yes, both collections are sorted by `Order`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you allow `foo` repetitions in cases where the bound `foo` is the same for several `bar` objects:

```
var result = bars.Zip(foos, 
        (b,f) => Tuple.Create(b, foos.TakeWhile(foo => foo.Order <= b.Order).Last()));
```

Of course it's still less efficient than iterating, since `TakeWhile` will be called for each `bars` object (starting from the beginning each time)

What I mean by `foo` repetitions is that for an input such as

```
var foos = new [] { new Foo(1, "Foo1"), new Foo(3, "Foo3"), new Foo(5, "Foo5")};
var bars = new [] { new Bar(1, "Bar1"), new Bar(2, "Bar2") };
```

The result would be

```
{ 
    ((1, "Bar1"), (1, "Foo1")),
    ((2, "Bar2"), (1, "Foo1")) //Foo1 again
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `foos` are sorted by `Order`, you can do:

```
var fubars = from bar in bars
             let bestFoo = foos.TakeWhile(foo => foo.Order <= bar.Order)
                               .LastOrDefault()
             select new { Bar = bar, Foo = bestFoo };
```

Otherwise, I suggest sorting the `foos` first.

You can make this query much more efficient by using binary search (e.g. wih `Array.BinarySearch`) instead of linear search as in my sample.

Answer (score 0):

By using union() of Linq you can join 2 same element ordered collections...